# Unresolved External Symbol calling function

Tags: c++

I'm working on a assignment for class so this is only part of the code, but whenever I try to compile it I'm getting this error.

```
1>pass9.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl bestbuy(double,double,double)" (?bestbuy@@YAXNNN@Z) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\YoggieBear\Desktop\school\pass9\Debug\pass9.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Code is below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void bestbuy(double, double, double);
void discountresults (double, double);
void howmany(double, double);

int price1, price2, price3;

int main ()
{

cout<<"Please enter 3 prices.\n";//This tests function bestbuy.
cin>>price1>>price2>>price3; 
bestbuy(price1,price2,price3);
cout<<"Your lowest price entered was "<<price1<<" and it was the "<<price2<<" number you entered.\n";


system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

void bestbuy(double &val1,double &val2, double val3)
{
if (val1 < val2 && val1 < val3)
val2 = 1;
else if (val2 < val1 && val2 < val3)
    {val1 = val2;
     val2 = 2;}
else
   {val1 = val3;
    val2 = 3;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function declaration does not match your function definition.

Update it as below:

```
void bestbuy(double&, double&, double);
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize the function prototype had to have &s

Answer (score 0):

Your forward declaration is

```
void bestbuy(double, double, double);
```

And your attempt at definition is

```
void bestbuy(double &val1,double &val2, double val3)
```

They are clearly referring to two different functions. Both signatures have to match, either drop the references or add them to the forward declaration as well. What you are doing right now is forward declaring a function and defining an overload for that non defined function.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring the function as taking values, but define it as taking references. Change the declaration to `void bestbuy(double&, double&, double);`.